# how to merge two dimensional list with the same len

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have three list that are two dimensional and all three list have the same length.  I would like to merge all three list together and put them in order from small to large. Here's a example below

Here's my three list

```
a = [[2,4,6],[3,5,7],[6,8,10]]

b = [[5],[4],[9]]

c = [[32,40],[10,19],[5,43]]
```

I have tried using this code below. This code does work but I would like to put it in order

```
d = [x + y +z for x, y,z in zip(a,b,c)]
```

I would like my result to be something like this

```
d = [[2,4,5,6,32,40],[3,4,5,7,10,19],[5,6,8,9,10,43]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. This code will merge all list and put them in order

'd= [sorted(x + y +z) for x, y,z in zip(a, b,c)'